# Host shiny app for academia and peak usage

Tags: shiny-server, shiny

I've created a couple of tutorial-like shiny apps that I want my student to be able to access without having to install R on their local machine.

I am aware of [shiny server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny-server-pro/) (and [a free shiny server pro version for teachers](https://www.rstudio.com/pricing/academic-pricing/), which I should be elegible to) as well as of the different plans offered at [shinyapp.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/).

We would have about 600-700 students using the app but - as everybody might expect - there will be a significant peak usage in the month right before the final exam, hence I fear that even a 2000 active hours plan on [shinyapp.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/) might not be enough in this specific month but way to big when students are on holiday.

So my questions is:

1. Does anyone (other academics?) have (had) the same decision to make and has some advice/experience.
2. Are there any other alternative ways of getting the app to the public except: local, shiny server or shinyapps.io?

If this is the wrong platform to ask such a question please do point me to the appropriate one.

Comment: I would say this question is better suited for the [Shiny Discussion Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shiny-discuss)

Comment: Regarding Q2: no there is no other way.  You either host it on shinyapps.io or you host yourself on your own server

Comment: To me it sounds that you really need to collaborate IT service of your university. We have also "centre of teaching support and development"(probably bad translation) which hosts teaching webtools probably in our university they could help in these kind of problems. Using shiny apps in teaching has really big potential. Good luck!